# Communities: Cannot change home page to my custom Community Builder Page

Tags: community

The following help link seems to indicate that I can change my Communities home page to any of my custom Community Builder pages.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_community_home.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Unfortunately, I can't get the lookup box to find any of my pages.  The only 2 options that show are 'main' and 'login'.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusing anyone, custom Community Builder pages are not supported for usage in lightning communities alongside the Builder.  The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_community_home.htm&language=en_US&type=0) you pointed out specifically mentions:

> Personalize the standard community home page with company branding by
>   using a custom Community Builder (Site.com Studio) or Visualforce
>   page.

The functionality you are referring to is changing the default home page of your lightning community by a new page created using the community builder:

[image]

This is not supported (at the moment).

Comment: Thanks for the response glls.  We're using Lightning Napoli for our pages.  Is there not a way to set one of those as a home page?

Comment: ahh, i see what you mean. Unfortunately, you cannot change the home landing page (unless you use visualforce and redirects).

Comment: sorry, your post title was a bit misleading, what you are trying is not supported. updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Update: Realized this is question is a few years old - but the limitation still seems to be there and I was able to get around it with the mentioned technique.  Feel free to update/correct anything here which goes against any established best practices!

While not my idea, the solution mentioned in bottom comment by "Sean Osterday" in the link below actually did end up working for my use case.  I had created a New Lightning community page in the builder and wanted this page to be the default landing page.

I went to the default home page and went to add a new page assignment, from there I was able to create a new page (mimicking my already created page not sure why I had to do this as I wasn't able to reference my existing page from this menu).  Once the new page was created I was able to  go back into the menu and make that custom page variant I just created previously to the default homepage.

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DhXnQAK

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If utilizing the standard Login Page, you can use the following setting of the Login Form component:
[image]